# useState does not update the state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to update a state using useState hook, however the state won't update. I've checked how to fix it but really have no idea about it what cause this point. This is the whole code I didnt include the urls and import files...

When onchange method trigger ilceZoom  function event has value so ı can get it evt.value example values is "1234" but I can not set it using useState future

```
const ilceUrl = 'URL';


const AddressSearchMaks = (props) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        ilceLoad();
    }, []);

    const [ ilceler, setIlceler ] = useState([]);
    const [ selectedIlce, setSelectedIlce ] = useState(null);


    let queryTask;
    let query;
    let sfs;
    let lineSymbol;
    let polygon;
    let polyline;
    let graphic;
    let extent;
    let point;
    let wMercatorUtils;
    let rfConverter;

    loadModules([
        'esri/tasks/query',
        'esri/tasks/QueryTask',
        'esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol',
        'esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol',
        'esri/geometry/Polygon',
        'esri/geometry/Polyline',
        'esri/geometry/webMercatorUtils',
        'esri/geometry/Extent',
        'esri/geometry/Point',
        'esri/graphic',
        'esri/Color',
        'libs/ReferenceConverter'
    ]).then(
        (
            [
                Query,
                QueryTask,
                SimpleFillSymbol,
                SimpleLineSymbol,
                Polygon,
                Polyline,
                webMercatorUtils,
                Extent,
                Point,
                Graphic,
                Color,
                referenceConverter
            ]
        ) => {
            queryTask = QueryTask;
            query = Query;
            polygon = Polygon;
            polyline = Polyline;
            graphic = Graphic;
            extent = Extent;
            point = Point;
            wMercatorUtils = webMercatorUtils;
            rfConverter = referenceConverter;
            sfs = new SimpleFillSymbol(
                SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
                new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new Color([ 0, 255, 255 ]), 4),
                new Color([ 140, 140, 140, 0.25 ])
            );
            lineSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new Color([ 0, 255, 255 ]), 4).setWidth(4);
        }
    );

    const getAdres = async (url) => {
        let response = await fetch(url);
        let data = await response.json();
        let list = [];
        data.AdresList.Adresler.Adres.forEach((item) => {
            list.push({
                label: item.ADI,
                value: item.ID,
                lat: item.LAT,
                lon: item.LON
            });
        });
        return list;
    };

    async function ilceLoad() {
        let ilceList = await getAdres(ilceUrl);
        setIlceler(ilceList);
    }

    const convertExtent = (lat, lon) => {
        let p;
        let ext;
        const sr = props.map.spatialReference;
        if (sr.wkid == 102100) {
            const _p = wMercatorUtils.lngLatToXY(lon, lat);
            ext = extent({
                xmin: _p[0],
                ymin: _p[1],
                xmax: _p[0],
                ymax: _p[1],
                spatialReference: props.map.spatialReference
            });
        } else {
            const res = rfConverter.WgsToItrf(lat, lon);
            ext = extent({
                xmin: res.x,
                ymin: res.y,
                xmax: res.x,
                ymax: res.y,
                spatialReference: props.map.spatialReference
            });
            p = point(res.x, res.y);
        }
        p.spatialReference = sr;
        return ext;
    };

    const ilceZoom = (evt) => {
        setSelectedIlce(evt.value);
        console.log('selectedIlce', selectedIlce);
        setError(false);
        console.log('error', error);
        const qTask = queryTask(maksIlce);
        const q = query();
        q.returnGeometry = true;
        q.outFields = [ '*' ];
        q.outSpatialReference = { wkid: 5254 };
        q.where = `KIMLIKNO=${evt.value}`;
        qTask.execute(q, (evt) => {
            const polyGon = polygon({
                rings: evt.features[0].geometry.rings
            });
            props.map.graphics.add(graphic(polyGon, sfs));
        });
        const extent = convertExtent(evt.lat, evt.lon);
        props.map.setExtent(extent);
        mahalleLoad();
    };



    return (

            <Select name='adresSelect' options={ilceler} onChange={(e) => ilceZoom(e)} placeholder='İlçe Seçiniz' />

    );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    map: state.map.map
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(AddressSearchMaks);
```

Comment: Are you sure the event has a value? Maybe event.target.value?

Comment: yes evt.value has value

Comment: can you upload whole component's code?

Comment: lets say I do have one more error state when I update it in same place setError(true) it  is really update it :( but it doesnt update the state of setSelectedIlce

Comment: It seems fine. when I use  `setSelectedIlce('deneme');` under the `ilceZoom()` it set selected ilce as 'deneme'. do not confuse with this line `console.log('selectedIlce', selectedIlce);` because setState works async so it can finish later setState.

Answer (score 0):

It can be related for some environment binding issue. Try to use the the setState as function:

```
useEffect(() => {
        ilceLoad();
    }, []);

    const [ ilceler, setIlceler ] = useState([]);
    const [ selectedIlce, setSelectedIlce ] = useState(null);

async function ilceLoad() {
        let ilceList = await getAdres(ilceUrl);
        setIlceler(ilceList); // update the state, it works here 
    }

const ilceZoom = (evt) => {
        setSelectedIlce(prev => {
          console.log("prev: ", prev);
          console.log("evt.value: ", evt.value);
          return evt.value;
        }); 
        const qTask = queryTask(url);
        const q = query();
        q.returnGeometry = true;
        q.outFields = [ '*' ];
        q.outSpatialReference = { wkid: 5254 };
        q.where = `VARIABLE NAME=${evt.value}`;
        qTask.execute(q, (evt) => {
            const polyGon = polygon({
                rings: evt.features[0].geometry.rings
            });
            props.map.graphics.add(graphic(polyGon, sfs));
        });
        const extent = convertExtent(evt.lat, evt.lon);
        props.map.setExtent(extent);
    };
```

Comment: still value is null :(

Comment: try to log out the prev, and the evt.value in the setState scope like: 
`setSelectedIlce(prev => {
  console.log("prev: ", prev);
  console.log("evt.value: ", evt.value);
  return evt.value;
})`

Comment: prev:  null, evt.value:  1739 still cant update the state

Comment: I guess your state updated correctyl, but the display, or reusage can have some mistake

Comment: Can you update 2 times in a row, if it remembers the #1 change at #2 .nd time?

Comment: Sir, i didnt get what you really mean ?

Comment: Use the function 2 times. At the first time the console had: prev: null, evt.value: 1739, at second time it should be prev: 1739, evt.value: some-new-value

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this. Because, in your code, you setting the data in selectedIlce, but before it re-render, your trying to checking the value in the console, so better use your console outside the event function, so that when it get updated, it will reflect in the console.

```
    console.log('selectedIlce', selectedIlce);
    const ilceZoom = (evt) => {
       setSelectedIlce(evt.value);
       ....
    }
```